# IndexOf two HashSet strings - shared preferences

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hi there I have two string sets which I would like to get the index of which currently exist as this:

I want to use the same index in the first set for the second set so I can use these string elsewhere, so if the token I had was **"VatU5fy1U4cgTc3uBBiGX7G7kuT2"** then the relevant date of birth would be **"8th February 2011"**. (See output below).

Now I understand sets are unordered and index cannot be used as I am using methods from Shared Preferences such as getStringSet which retrieves the strings in only a set and not an array.

I have tried to convert the set to an array but everytime I used index I always have -1 returned to me, where the string cannot be found! :(

Here is my current code (pretty much standard and it works perfectly) for shared preferences for dates which is same for the other token set:

```
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Set<String> myDates = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("myDates", new HashSet<String>());

    String dates = sharedPreferences.getString("savedDate", "");
// Add the new value.
    myDates.add(dates);


// Save the list.
    editor.putStringSet("myDates", myDates);
    editor.commit();


    Log.w(TAG, "Onexit value of dates in array: " + String.valueOf(myDates));
```

**Output:**

```
Onexit value of tokens in array: [Ztg4GOqeucd6CqNAEokUe7eRHhY2, VatU5fy1U4cgTc3uBBiGX7G7kuT2]
Onexit value of dates in array: ["8th February 2012", "8th February 2011"]
```

Here are my attempted solutions to convert and treat these lists as arrays:

```
**//Attempt 1**

    Set<String> myDates = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("myDates", new 
    HashSet<String>());

    List<String> myDatesList = new ArrayList <String> (myDates);
    int i = Arrays.asList(myDatesList).indexOf(dates);        

    myDates.add(dates);

    List<String> myDatesList = new ArrayList <String> (myDates);

    editor.putStringSet("myDates", myDates);
    editor.commit();

int i = Arrays.asList(myDatesList).indexOf(dates);
```

**returns -1** ^

```
**//Attempt 2**

List<String> myDatesList = new ArrayList <String> (myDates);
String datesString = TextUtils.join(";", myDatesList);
editor.putString("newdates", datesString);
editor.apply();


final String datesString = sharedPreferences.getString("newdates", "");
String dates = sharedPreferences.getString("savedDate", "");
List<String> myDatesList = new ArrayList<>();
editor.commit();
if (!datesString.isEmpty()){
    myDatesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(datesString.split(";")));
}

String datesString = TextUtils.join(";", myDatesList);
editor.putString("newdates", datesString);
editor.apply();
int i = Arrays.asList(datesString).indexOf(dates);
**returns -1** ^
```

**response to answer - UPDATE **

**in response to comment: (I CHANGED LOG)**

```
        int i = myDatesList.indexOf(datesString);
        Log.w(TAG, "My dates list: " + dates + " and datesString is: " + datesString + i);
```

Gives me:

```
My dates list: "9th August 2017" and datesString is: "9th August 2017"0
My dates list: "9th February 2011" and datesString is: "9th August 2017";"9th February 2011"-1
```

Why did it give me -1 second time and not 1?

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` takes in varargs, and is not for making a copy of a `Collection` type, but for creating a `List<T>` where `T` is the type of object being passed in as a parameter.

What's happening is when you have:

```
// Contains each element from myDates
List<String> myDatesList = new ArrayList<String>(myDates);
```

And call `Arrays.asList(myDatesList).indexOf(dates)`, what that `Arrays.asList()` call is returning is an instance of `List<List<String>>`.

```
// This is what's actually being returned:
List<List<String>> result = Arrays.asList(myDatesList);
```

In that case, calling `indexOf()` with a `String` type will never find a match (as a `String` will never be equal to a `List<String>`. In fact, this `String` parameter should appear as a warning in your IDE, indicating that `List<List<String>> may not contain objects of type String`.

You already have a `List<String>` (`myDatesList`) so there is no need to call `Arrays.asList()` as that is intended to create a `List` of the type passed in. Just call `myDatesList.indexOf(dateString)` to get the actual index.

Comment: +1 thanks for your help and understanding your answer gave me. However after trying this index still gives me -1, I will update answer

Comment: Take time to inspect the log message that you added above, with that in mind it should be clear why it's not found in the list.

Comment: Hi looked at the log message and really not sure why it is not found in the list? they are both string so no idea why it is not showing in the list when two values are clearly the same?

Comment: `My dates list: "8th February 2011"`, and `datesString is: "8th February 2012";"8th February 2011"` -- they are not the same.

Comment: 8th February 2011 exists in date string? Ok i am about to give up :(((

Comment: You are looking for the literal string `"8th February 2012";"8th February 2011"` in a list that contains only `"8th February 2011"`.

Comment: +1 ok my bad i managed to get 0!! then when another string was entered i got -1 haha, im going to update question